# How to automatically run inferior process when loading major mode for the first time?

Tags: python, company-mode, matlab

Let's say we are working with Python (or Matlab) with company.
Without an inferior process company messages that

```
Completion needs an inferior Python process running
```

However, the obvious solution to automatically run an inferior process

```
 (add-hook 'python-mode 'run-python)
```

would run a new python process every time I open a .py file (this becomes more expensive with Matlab)

Is there a hook that gets run only the first time a major mode is run ? 
Or is there a way to detect if a python/matlab inferior process is already running ? 
Or is there another way to solve this problem of running an inferior process automatically with a major mode but only once ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FYI, some modes open only one inferior processs. For example, `run-python` will open an inferior process only if there isn't already an inferior process running. What you suggested with `run-python` actually does what you want.

For other modes (Matlab?), you could use a function that unhooks itself, like so:

```lisp
(defun run-python-once ()
  (remove-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python-once)
  (run-python))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python-once)
```

Note that on Emacs 24.5 (and older?), `run-python` takes a mandatory `CMD` argument, so the solution will be:

```lisp
(defun run-python-once ()
  (remove-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python-once)
  (run-python (python-shell-parse-command)))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python-once)
```

Comment: It seems like the `run-python` function takes a required arg: `(run-python CMD &optional DEDICATED SHOW)`. It works fine interactively, but when this hook executes I get a `Wrong number of arguments` error.

Comment: Thanks, the argument is optional in Emacs 25, but not in 24.5. I updated the answer with a fixed solution for Emacs 24.5