# How to automatically run inferior process when loading major mode?

Tags: init-file, python, shell

Like suggested in this question [How to automatically run inferior process when loading major mode for the first time?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10167/how-to-automatically-run-inferior-process-when-loading-major-mode-for-the-first) I want to automatically run `run-python` when entering python major mode. However,

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python)
```

doesn't work and gives the error

```
Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 3), 0
```

Which argument is needed by `run-python`? How to automatically start an inferior python interpreter when entering `python-mode`?

Edit: After `M-x` `toggle-debug-on-error` the output gives

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (1 . 3) 0)
run-python()
run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook python-mode-hook)
apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook python-mode-hook))
run-mode-hooks(python-mode-hook)
python-mode()
call-interactively(python-mode record nil)
command-execute(python-mode record)
execute-extended-command(nil "python-mode")
call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: What you tried would actually work. Technically `run-python` doesn't require any arguments, at least not in the version of Emacs that I have. You could do `C-h f` `run-python` to see what's the function signature you have, though I'm almost sure the error comes from some other place. `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` would help to find the problem.

Comment: I'm using Emacs ver. `24.5.1` and also tried an empty init.el with only `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python)` in it. `C-h f` `run-python` gives the signature `(run-python CMD &optional DEDICATED SHOW)`. For debug output see edited question above. I tried an Emacs ver. `23.4.1` on a different machine and indeed there is `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python)` working as expected.

Comment: For some reason on your machine `run-python` requires `CMD` argument... well, if that's the case you could change your code to `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (run-python (python-shell-calculate-command)))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at documentation of `run-python`, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`run-python` you would notice that requires on parameter `cmd`. When that command is called interactively emacs calculates that parameter (see [Using interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) or <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`interactive` to understand the mechanism). However when called from elisp, the `cmd` need to be explicitly passed.

There are couple of ways to solve this -

1) Write a custom function which calls `run-python` with proper arguments, something like following, and add it to `python-mode-hook`

```el
(defun my-run-python ()
    (run-python (python-shell-parse-command)))
```

**EDIT**

After understanding your problems with the above approach I came up with the following function, hopefully this is what you are looking for

```el
(defun my-run-python ()
  (save-selected-window
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window (process-buffer (python-shell-get-or-create-process (python-shell-parse-command))))))
```

2) Add the function `python-shell-switch-to-shell` which does not expect any arguments, to `python-mode-hook`

Comment: Is it possible to see which arguments are passed to `run-python` when called interactively? Neither your first suggestion nor the second gives the same result as calling `run-python` or pressing `C-c C-p`. The first one doesn't create a new window with the python process (I'll have to do it manually) and the second asks me to manually input the parameters every time.

Comment: I accomplished it with my basic knowledge of Emacs Lisp: `(defun run-python-once ()
  (remove-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python-once)
  (switch-to-buffer (last-buffer))
  (run-python (python-shell-parse-command))
  (split-window-sensibly)
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window (python-shell-get-buffer))
  )` added to `python-mode-hook`. But that doesn't seem pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: The problem with `(lambda () (run-python (python-shell-parse-command) nil t))` added to `python-mode-hook` is, that an opened file doesn't show up. A new window is created and the inferior python process is shown, but the first window dosen't change to the newly opened file buffer.

Comment: @max0r I have edited the answer to mention an alternative approach hopefully it resolves your current issues.