# run-python does not work if added to python-mode-hook

Tags: python, hooks, process, ipython, inferior-buffer

I would like the Python inferior process to start (if it is not already running) whenever I create a `python-mode` buffer (for example, by visiting a .py file).

Some functions in anaconda-mode etc. depend on an inferior Python process running.  Also, I want to be able to <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> and see the output.

Everything works fine if I create the `python-mode` buffer, then manually run <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>run-python</kbd>.

However, if I run `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'run-python)`, then create a `python-mode` buffer, I get no inferior Python process but this error:

`Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 3), 0`

I don't know if it's relevant, but I have this in my `custom.el`:

```
(defvar python-shell-interpreter "ipython")
(defvar python-shell-interpreter-args "-i")
```

I had thought that [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10167/how-to-automatically-run-inferior-process-when-loading-major-mode-for-the-first) would help but it doesn't.

Please could you advise how to create an inferior Python process if it is not already running?  Thanks in advance.

Versions:

- Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)
- prelude latest at time of writing
- Python 3.5.1 (Anaconda 2.5.0 64-bit)
- Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

Check the arguments that `run-python` requires, and supply them in your hook function that calls it (use a lambda with `interactive` or a named command that you defined). Otherwise, if you want to interact with it then use `call-interactively` in the mode-hook function.